# How to handle iFrame content in a .NET MAUI Blazor app?

Tags: iframe, blazor, maui

I have a .NET MAUI Blazor app.

I have added an iFrame for a payment system.

When payment is complete, the payment system redirects to a https webpage.

Either I need to handle content of page or callback address to redirect to an internal Blazor page in my app.

Could you advise me a scenario and how to do it in an Android and iOS app with .NET MAUI Blazor.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect the user back to an internal Blazor page within your app after payment completion, you'll need to utilize **JavaScript interop** to communicate between your Blazor code and the embedded iframe.

### JavaScript

```
function paymentCompletion() {
    // Check if the URL matches the payment success URL, and if so, trigger Blazor navigation.
    if (window.location.href === 'https://***/paymentsuccess') { 
        DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('BlazorAppName', 'NavigateToPage');
    }
}
```

### CS

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
 
@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // to call paymentCompletion javascript method
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("paymentCompletion");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is completely unrelated to this question. I had a problem that iFrame works on android but not on ios. I managed to find a workaround using WebView. No problem to open from blazor page xaml page.

I created a new xaml page and added there

```
<WebView Source="https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui" />
```

Documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?pivots=devices-android